# Is possible to enable uploading and disable downloading

Tags: dropbox

I have two laptops. First laptop I use every day, second about 1-2 times during a week (and most time it is in hibernate mode). So when it waked up, dropbox initiate uploading process that take many time. But very often I need just upload only single file from this machine.

So my question is:

Is there exists some capability (maybe plugin) that allow only uploading and prevent downloading

Comment: What you want goes against the very basic nature of Dropbox.  Dropbox has no way of knowing if a files exists in the cloud in its current form unless it downloads the current version.

Comment: In your preferences you can adjust your download rate. You could try setting it to 0, but that may have undesired effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Dropbox Uploader](http://www.andreafabrizi.it/?dropbox_uploader) ([code](https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader)). It works with MacOSX, Windows/Cygwin, and Unix. It allows file and recursive directory upload.

To upload a local file to a remote Dropbox folder:

```
$ ./dropbox_uploader.sh upload snort.pdf Documents/manuals
```

Example: recursive upload:

[image]

---

Alternatively, you can use the selective sync feature of Dropbox, if your laptops don't need to use the same folders:

[image]

Comment: Do you know if this script can run via cygwin?

Comment: @sunk818 Yep it can, done it with cygwin on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate!

Answer (score 0):

I currently use [GoodSync](http://www.goodsync.com/platforms) to back up files to DropBox and Google Drive. I don't need to sync with my others computers, so it is handy to have a program that will just perform 1 one way (backup) sync. It is pay software, but may be useful for those that are not comfortable using command line or scripts.