# Keep a folder in my Dropbox account while moving it somewhere else on my hard drive

Tags: dropbox

Folder X is in the Dropbox folder and is synchronized with my Dropbox account. I would like to keep this folder in my Dropbox account while moving it somewhere else on my hard drive (I don't want it to be synchronized anymore but would like to keep a snapshot in my Dropbox account). How can it achieve this?

What I've tried:

- Using Dropbox's selective synchronization removes the local folder
- Unistalling Dropbox works since the Dropbox folder and its contents [will remain intact](https://www.dropbox.com/help/41) after uninstall, but it is tedious.
- I'm aware of the [Dropbox Uploader](https://superuser.com/a/802400/116475) but it takes a while to upload small files and has no resume function (skipping files is just as slow as creating them).

Comment: Would a google drive example be useful? I don't have dropbox

Comment: @Prasanna Thanks but not really: I prefer to use Dropbox as I have an unlimited storage there, while only 100 GB in Google Drive :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

1. Pause syncing
2. Move the folder out of the Dropbox folder
3. Remove the folder from the Dropbox's selective synchronization
4. Resume syncing

Comment: If you move the folder out of Dropbox folder, you have **unlimited** version history for Business version. For Personal, you get 30 days. Unless you want to keep history longer than 30 days, the steps you mention may be unnecessary.